# Async / sync: how can I be sure a Javascript function will execute after the for loop?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous

For instance, I have this code:

```js
var smth = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Some long function I call from elsewhere
    for (var k = 0; k < 10000; k++) {
       smth += k + ' '; 
    }
    smth += i;
}
console.log(smth);
```

Can I be sure that `console.log` will always execute after the `for` cycles are finished processing my `smth` parameter?

What about all the async / sync executions? How would I rewrite the code so that `console.log` executes at the same time as the `for` cycle?

Comment: This could help https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions

Comment: Could you give any more details as to what this "long function" does?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript executes the code synchronously i.e. one line at a time. Which means the console.log statement will be executed after the for loops have completed their execution.

Answer (score 1):

`for loop` are blocking tasks, so in this case your `console.log()` will be always executed **AFTER** the for loop.

Comment: And `foreach`? Are they also blocking? Are any loops non-blocking?

Comment: Javascript is a single-threaded environment, only async functions are...well *async*

Answer (score 1):

> Can I be sure that console.log will always execute after the for cycles are finished processing my smth parameter?

Yes. There's nothing asynchronous.

> What about all the async / sync executions?

You don't have any async code there.

> How would I rewrite the code so that console.log executes at the same time as the for cycle?

You'd need to make the code non-blocking. There's nothing in core JavaScript for this. Some host environments provide a form of threading via workers.

- [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) for browsers.
- [Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) for Node.js.